# Adding a Img in a Dropdown Menu?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, radzen

I'm programming in blazorframework with Radzen components a webapplication with a registration page.
I need from the user the phone number with his country code. To select the country code I have a dropdown menu with the country abbreviations ("DE | US | AC") I would like to have the appropriate flage on the left of it.
Is there a way to do this.

[Look at my Dropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wWXO.png)

**This is the HTML Part of the Dropdown**

```
         <RadzenDropDown Data=@CountryCodes style="width:80px !important; top:9px;"
            AllowFiltering="true"
            FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
            FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.StartsWith"
            TValue="string"
            Class="w-100"
            @bind-Value=@_value>
         <RadzenDropDown/>
```

I fill the dropdown with a nuget "libPhonenumbers"

```
    public HashSet<string> CountryCodes => PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance().GetSupportedRegions();
```

Comment: You can try by using `<Template></Template>`, I don't know if it supports HTML. [Radzen examples](https://blazor.radzen.com/dropdown)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Yes <Template> works with html but how do i implemnt all flags, and macth the with the right country code

Comment: What is your issue? How to get the ISO of the countries, how to select the right flags to display, how to display them or even another issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [flag emojis](https://emojipedia.org/flags/). You need a method to convert country codes to flag emojis. You also need to use a font that supports flag emojis e.g. [Noto Color Emoji](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji) to make the flags [appear on windows](https://prinsfrank.nl/2021/01/25/Non-existing-flag-emojis-on-windows). In the following example I'm using a simple `select` element but you can easily modify for `RadzenDropDown`.

```cs
<select @bind="_selectedCountryCode">
    <option disabled>Select country code</option>
    @foreach(var country in Countries)
    {
        <option value="@country.CountryCode">@country.FlagEmoji</option>
    }
</select>

<p>Selected country code: @_selectedCountryCode</p>

@code {
    private string _selectedCountryCode;
    private HashSet<string> CountryCodes = new HashSet<string> { "DE", "US", "AC" };

    private List<Country> Countries => CountryCodes
        .Select(x => new Country
        {
            CountryCode = x,
            FlagEmoji = IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(x)
        })
        .ToList();

    private string IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(string countryCode) =>
        string.Concat(countryCode.ToUpper().Select(x => char.ConvertFromUtf32(x + 0x1F1A5)));

    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string FlagEmoji { get; set; }      
    }
}
```

[BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/np637d0k)

[How to convert country name to flag emoji article](https://itnext.io/convert-country-name-to-flag-emoji-in-c-the-net-ecosystem-115f714d3ef9)

**`RadzenDropDown` example:**

```
<RadzenDropDown Data="@Countries"
                style="width: 80px !important; top: 9px;"
                AllowFiltering="true"
                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.StartsWith"
                TValue="string"
                TextProperty="@nameof(Country.FlagEmoji)"
                ValueProperty="@nameof(Country.CountryCode)"
                Class="w-100"
                @bind-Value=@_selectedCountryCode>
</RadzenDropDown>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your select is working perfectly now im struggling to convert it to a radzen dropdown.

Comment: You have to use `TextProperty` and `ValueProperty` parameters. Added `RadzenDropDown ` example in my answer.

Comment: Okay now it is running perfectly

Comment: do you happen to know how to get the numbers (+49....) after the country flags?

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/QPTLWsS6. The code can be refactored to become cleaner.

Comment: You are soo good thanks a lot